# How to update SQL Server to restore databases backups?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to restore backups from one server to another, I already ran the update services but I'm still stuck with this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore of database 'Consolidado' failed.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 15.00.2070. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 14.00.2027. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

What should I do?

Comment: You **cannot** restore a database from a SQL Server **2019** (v15) to a server running SQL Server **2017** (v14). The easiest is to run the **same version** of SQL Server on all platforms. If you can't do that - you need to script your changes into `.sql` scripts on the 2019 machine, and then execute those SQL scripts on the down-level version of SQL server

Comment: I'm going to try uninstalling sql server from my computer and install 2019 version, thank you